# Wi-Fi card doesn't work on Dell

Tags: wireless, dell

I am new on askUbuntu so I hope I am doing everything in the right way.

I have the following problem. I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7000. I have just installed Ubuntu 14 but my Wi-Fi doesn't work. I am reading everywhere how to do to solve my issue but I cannot solve it. Obviously the Ethernet works properly.

Can someone help me? Is there a way to use solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu , please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/848902/edit) and add the output of `lspci -knn | grep net -A2`